# Blogging CMS with voting and some premium-only posts

Tags: cms, blog, voting

I want a CMS for blogging which users can create a new post, other users can put comments on that particular post and also rank that post. I also want to make some posts and their comments only visible for some premium users.

Have you got any suggestion for this kind of CMS?

Comment: Do you want anyone to be able to create a post? Do you need the premium subscription purchase to be integrated in the CMS, or are you going to handle that with some other software?

Comment: yes i want anyone to write posts and also premium subscription purchase integrated in the cms